# Issues with make execution order

Tags: c++, terminal, makefile

This is a make file I have wrote with the current goal of turning all c++ files in a directory into object files. My issue is that it always executes g++ first then any other commands second.

```
CC=g++
CPPFLAGS=`pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
SRCS=$(wildcard classes/source/*.cc)
PROGS=$(patsubst %.cc,%,$(SRCS))
CLASS_HEADERS=classes/
all: $(PROGS)
    mkdir -p build/release/objs 
%: %.cc
    $(CC) -I$(CLASS_HEADERS) -c $< -o build/release/objs/$(@F).o $(CPPFLAGS)
```

results in:

```
g++ -Iclasses/ -c classes/source/helloworld.cc -o build/release/objs/helloworld.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0`
mkdir -p build/release/objs
```

Thanks

Comment: Provide another dependency target for `build/release/objs`, and place that before `$(PROGS)`.

Comment: The rules for `all` say: make sure all the `$(PROGS)` are up to date; when that's done, running the `mkdir` will finish the job of creating `all`.  You need something more like `all: objdir $(PROGS)` where the rule for `objdir` might be: `objdir: ; mkdir -p build/release/objs` (where you'd use a newline and tab in place of the semicolon, though the notation shown does actually work on a single line).  This is just a longer version of what @πάνταῥεῖ said.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler you have solved my problem, and provided a great explanation to help me better understand how make works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest fix is to always issue `mkdir` before using the target directory.  If using the `-p` option, there's really no harm in executing this command redundantly.

```
%: %.cc
   mkdir -p build/release/objs
   $(CC) -I$(CLASS_HEADERS) -c $< -o build/release/objs/$(@F).o $(CPPFLAGS)
```

---

As noted in my answer to [GNU make's -j option](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1564195/86967): Although it may sometimes work, it is not correct to simply add a `mkdir` target as an initial dependency in your existing `all` dependency list.  In principle, these could be executed in any order (so `mkdir` wouldn't necessarily be first).  If you want to take the dependency-based approach, you have to start doing more complicated stuff.  For example using make recursively:

```
all: do_mkdir
   $(MAKE) $(progs)

do_mkdir:
   mkdir -p build/release/objs
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution could be creating a target for the object directory and place it before the build target:

```
......
OBJ_DIR := build/release/objs

all: create_obj_dir $(PROGS)

create_obj_dir:
    mkdir -p  $(OBJ_DIR)

%: %.cc
    $(CC) -I$(CLASS_HEADERS) -c $< -o $(OBJ_DIR)/$(@F).o $(CPPFLAGS)
```

Comment: Won't necessarily work if you use -j to run multiple make threads

Answer (score 1):

Recipes for a target are executed *after* any prerequisites, so when you make `all` make will go through `$(PROGS)` before running `mkdir`.

`build/release/objs` should be a prerequisite of the object files, because they can't be made unless the directory exists. The directory should also be an [order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Prerequisite-Types) because you don't want to remake every single object file if the dir timestamp changes.

Your pattern rule is [broken](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/)(see 2) as well, and you're using the wrong [flag variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables). You can also recycle the [built-in implicit rule for compiling](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

```
CXXFLAGS := $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-3.0)
CPPFLAGS := -Iclasses/
SRCS     := $(wildcard classes/source/*.cc)
OBJS     := $(SRCS:classes/source/%.cc=build/release/objs/%.o)

.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJS)

$(OBJS): build/release/objs/%.o: classes/source/%.cc | build/release/objs
    $(COMPILE.cc) $(OUTPUT_OPTION) $<

build/release/objs: ; mkdir -p $@
```

Side note: since you're only compiling `-libs gtkmm-3.0` probably shouldn't be in the flags, you provide libs when linking.

Comment: @Russeree Please accept the answer if it answered your question.